# WebDriver problems with element visibility in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, webdriver

WebDriver is telling me certain elements aren't visible when they definitely are, but only in IE - Firefox and Chrome work fine. The block of code involves radio buttons and other inputs. Some of the inputs are indeed hidden, but these aren't the ones I'm trying to interact with. I'm trying to select this radio button:

```
<input type="radio" onclick="onClickBranching()" id="rbOnCompletePres" value="2" name="rbBranchType">
```

I'm using the id for the locator, so basically `By.cssSelector("input#rbOnCompletePres")`. I can confirm that the findElement command works in both Firefox and IE, and I've printed out the element's attributes with IE to confirm that it's finding the right button. It's definitely finding the right button, the same one it found in Firefox. It's just convinced that the element isn't visible in IE.

There are some hidden elements above and below the element in question, a `div` and a `label` that are either meant to be permanently hidden or will activate when other radio buttons are selected. They are hidden by having `style="display: none"` set as attributes.

Is there some reason why WebDriver (especially on IE only) would decide that visible elements are not visible based on other elements in the vicinity?

I tried using one workaround to inject JS that would make the element visible, but ran into two problems: the first was that I wasn't certain I was eliminating the style attribute properly, the other was that the element, even as reported by WebDriver, doesn't actually have any attributes that make it hidden, so there's nothing to unset.

Another workaround I tried which worked was to use JS to execute the click, since it ignores visibility. I just don't like it - especially because my next action is to fill out a text field which WebDriver *also* thinks is invisible, undoubtedly for the same reasons.

Is there any explanation for this behavior? Or should I just chalk it up to IE being weird and use JS? Thanks.

Comment: Hi @rironin which version of webdriver, IEDriver_Server and IE are you using?